# Laravel5: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

error message :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'schoolstore_laravel.sells.xid' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: 
select `sells`.*, `items`.`item_title`, 
   `items`.`item_id`, group_concat(items.item_title SEPARATOR ", ") 
from `sells` 
inner join `items` 
   on `sells`.`item_id` = `items`.`item_id` 
where `sells`.`created_at` like 2018-04-14% 
group by `sells`.`ticket_number`)
```

code is

```
$buyLists = Sell::join('items', 'sells.item_id', '=', 'items.item_id')
        ->select('sells.*', 'items.item_title', 'items.item_id')
        ->selectRaw(DB::raw('group_concat(items.item_title SEPARATOR ", ")'))
        ->where('sells.created_at', 'like', $timeCheck->format('Y-m-d') . '%')
        ->groupBy('sells.ticket_number')
        ->get();
```

blade code

```
@foreach($groupedBuyLists as $ticketNumber => $sells)
 <tr>
   <td>{{ $ticketNumber }}</td>
   <td>{{ $title = implode(', ', $sells->pluck('item_title')->all()) }}</td>
   <td>{{ $sells->status }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You can't select all `sells` columns when you use `GROUP BY` this way. The database doesn't know which row to pick for each value of `sells.ticket_number`. Do you need all those columns?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, but it's much more complicated. So you need all columns?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir yes!

Comment: Which `sells` row do you want to get if there are multiple per `sells.ticket_number`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I want to bring it all.

Comment: I think you have a wrong understanding of `GROUP BY`: It returns only one row per value of `sells.ticket_number`. What's the goal of your query?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I want to import all rows of sells. Is there a way?

Comment: Does each `Sell` have one `Item`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes!

Comment: Why are you using `group_concat`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The number of ```ticket_number``` will be merged when the same row is present.

Comment: You want a string with all values of `item_title` per value of `sells.ticket_number`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes i want it !

Comment: Then you can't include data from other `sells` columns.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Is there any way I can include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different approach. Get all sells and items from the database and then group them:

```php
$buyLists = Sell::join('items', 'sells.item_id', '=', 'items.item_id')
    ->select('sells.*', 'items.item_title')
    ->whereDate('sells.created_at', $timeCheck)
    ->get();
$groupedBuyLists = $buyLists->groupBy('ticket_number');
foreach($groupedBuyLists as $ticketNumber => $sells) {
    $title = implode(', ', $sells->pluck('item_title')->all());
    foreach($sells as $sell) {
        // $sell->status
    } 
}
```

For `items` you should use a [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) and [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) instead of a `JOIN`.

Comment: how can i print ?

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: I want to output the results of ```buyLists```

Comment: `dd($buyLists);`

Comment: How can I output the combined result to the blade of the ```ticket_number``` is duplicated?

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop and `implode` as I've demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: How can I output other values to ```sells```?

Comment: For example, I want to output the ```status``` of ```sells```.  (```sells.status```)

Comment: The status is superimposed on the blade.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If there are several ```ticket_number```, multiple statuses are nested. If ```ticket_number``` is duplicated, is it possible to print only one duplicate?

Comment: Do you use `$buyLists` or `$groupedBuyLists`?

Comment: `$sells` is an array of all `sells` with the same `ticket_number`. What should `{{ $sells->status }}` print?

Comment: Yes, I want to print all the rows in the ```sells```.
Please see my updated question.

Comment: Then you have to use another `foreach` loop, as my answer shows.

Comment: If used  foreach in foreach, print multiple ```ticket_number```. I want to use ```ticket_number``` to leave only one duplicate state value.

Comment: For the last time: What do you expect? A comma separated list of `status` values (as with `item_title`)?

Comment: If the ```ticket_number``` of ```sells``` is the same value, the ```status``` of ```sells``` has multiple values. I want to output only one of them. The value of ```status``` is the same.

Comment: `{{ $sells[0]->status }}`

Comment: Thank you very much. Resolved. Thank you very much for your help.